# Promises, .then and message

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've been struggling with promises and .then(), I have managed to create my two promises and they run, I think, however the ordering is still wrong, the first promise gets an updated spreadsheet and the next one does stuff to that spreadsheet and sends mails with that sheets data, no matter what I do I can't get the ordering to be correct. The message "Done fetching latest Drive sheet.." always prints after the mailing rules have run but it should be before. The getNewSheet promise should run, and then the sendMails promise should.  Why isn't getNewSheet() running and then .sendMails?

Please help me understand why this isn't running and what I am doing wrong with the promises, additionally why isnt the message method of the promise return their values? I assume because the promise wasn't resolved in the correct order.

Please note I am still learning and using environment variables for some variables, I have edited out what I can, its a bit long but I am curious if I need to do something further with the containing code/functions in each promise before it would successful.

EDITED: Edited code to be more accurate.

```
            let getNewSheet = function () {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    const fs = require("fs");
                    const readline = require("readline");
                    const {
                        google
                    } = require("googleapis");

                    const SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
                    const TOKEN_PATH = "token.json";

                    fs.readFile("credentials.json", (err, content) => {
                        if (err) return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
                        authorize(JSON.parse(content), getLatestListFromDrive);
                    });
                    function authorize(credentials, callback) {
                        const {
                            client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
                        const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
                            client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]
                        );

                        fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
                            if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
                            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
                            callback(oAuth2Client);
                        });
                    }
                    function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
                        const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
                            access_type: "offline",
                            scope: SCOPES
                        });
                        console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl);
                        const rl = readline.createInterface({
                            input: process.stdin,
                            output: process.stdout
                        });
                        rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", code => {
                            rl.close();
                            oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
                                if (err) return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);
                                oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
                                fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), err => {
                                    if (err) console.error(err);
                                    console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
                                });
                                callback(oAuth2Client);
                            });
                        });
                    }

                    function getLatestListFromDrive(auth) {
                        const drive = google.drive({
                            version: "v3",
                            auth
                        });
                        var fileId = process.env.NODE_DRIVE_FILE_ID;
                        var dest = fs.createWriteStream("" + appDir + "\\tmp\\feedbacklist.xlsx");

                        drive.files.export({
                            fileId: fileId,
                            mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                        }, {
                                responseType: "stream"
                            },
                            function (err, res) {
                                res.data
                                    .on("end", () => {
                                    })
                                    .on("error", err => {
                                        console.log("Error", err);
                                    })
                                    .pipe(dest);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                    resolve();
                });

            };

            var path = require("path");
            var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
            let sendMails = function () {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    const XLSX = require("xlsx");
                    const workbook = XLSX.readFile("" + appDir + "\\tmp\\feedbacklist.xlsx", {
                        type: "binary",
                        cellDates: true,
                        dateNF: "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
                    });
                    const SheetNameList = workbook.SheetNames;
                    var rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[SheetNameList[0]], {
                        raw: false
                    });
                    var raw = workbook.Sheets[SheetNameList[0]];
                    var today = new Date();
                    today = today.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                    var dateYesterday = new Date();
                    dateYesterday.setDate(dateYesterday.getDate() - 1);
                    dateYesterday = dateYesterday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                    var dayYesterday = new Date();
                    var days = [
                        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
                    ];
                    dayYesterday.setDate(dayYesterday.getDate() - 1);
                    dayYesterday = days[dayYesterday.getDay()];
                    var dateTomorrow = new Date();
                    dateTomorrow.setDate(dateTomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                    dateTomorrow = dateTomorrow.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                    var dayTomorrow = new Date();
                    var futureDays = [
                        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
                    ];
                    dayTomorrow.setDate(dayTomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                    dayTomorrow = futureDays[dayTomorrow.getDay()];

                    var filteredRows = rows.filter(eachRow);
                    function eachRow(eachRow) {
                        return eachRow["tourDate"] === dateYesterday;
                    }
                    if (filteredRows != 0) {
                        for (x = 0; x < filteredRows.length; x++) {

                            console.log(filteredRows[x].emailAddress);
                            console.log(filteredRows[x].fName);
                            console.log(filteredRows[x].tourDate);
                            console.log(filteredRows[x].feedbacksent);
                            var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

                            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                                host: process.env.NODEMAILER_SERVICE,
                                secure: false,
                                auth: {
                                    user: process.env.NODEMAILER_USER,
                                    pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASS
                                }
                            });
                            var mailOptions = {
                                from: process.env.NODEMAILER_FROM,
                                to: "" + filteredRows[x].emailAddress + "",
                                subject: "Hi",
                                html: "Hi ",
                                text: "Hi "
                            };
                            console.log("I've sent a feedback request to " + filteredRows[x].emailAddress);
                            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                                //check for console errors
                                if (error) {
                                    console.log(error);
                                } else {
                                    console.log(
                                        "Feedback request sent to " +
                                        filteredRows[x].emailAddress
                                    );

                                };

                            })
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("No rows/records to process for yesterday..");
                    }
                    resolve();

                });
            };

            getNewSheet(console.log("drive fetched")).then(function (result) {
                console.log("mails sent");
                return sendMails(result);

            }).then(function () {
                console.log("promises finished");
            });
```

Comment: can you reduce this code to only its relevant part? This is a lot to process

Comment: I will edit now,thank you

Comment: please reduce your code its really hard to read and explain well

Comment: You seem to resolve `getNewSheet` promise before it even reads credentials file. `fs.readFile` is asynchronous operation.

Comment: Thank you, I have reduced as much as possible, @Anastazy the request works in my test case, it does retrieve the Drive data but why isnt sendMails waiting for getNewSheet?

Comment: @user3206244 see my answer for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `resolve` and `reject` functions when the operations you had scheduled, were actually completed.

Remember that when dealing with asynchronous operations, the code you write is executed out of order, meaning not in the order it is written in the file.

Consider these examples:

*Will not work*

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  let result
  fs.someAsyncOperation(function (data) {
    result = data
  })
  resolve(result) // the promise will resolve immediately with undefined value
}
```

*Will work*

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  fs.someAsyncOperation(function (result) {
    resolve(result) // the promise will resolve after async operation is completed
  })
}
```

Your code should be reworked to wait for the results of asynchronous operation before calling `resolve` function.

Comment: Thanks @Anastazy, I have moved each then both resolves to see the results but I am still getting the mails sent before the latest drive sheet is retrieved, I thank you kindly for your detailed and patient reply, I will keep testing.

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect my changes and same result, currently if I make a change to the drive file when I run the file it doesnt get the latest version but rather only after the second run does it get the newest info. Am I resolving promises before they are complete?

Comment: Yes, you need to move `resolve()` calls. In `getNewSheet` function, the last async operation I see is inside the `getLatestListFromDrive` function, in the callback passed to `drive.files.export`. There is a section with `res.data.on("end", () => {})`, which probably should have your `resolve` call in it. Another issue would be inside `sendMails` function, where last async operation seem to be `transporter.sendMail` call. The `resolve` call should be inside `else` clause in the callback you pass to `sendMail` call.

Comment: Brilliant! That was it, I was just not sure where exactly to place them but that makes heaps of sense. Thank you, thank you @Anastazy!

Comment: @user3206244 I know you'll do the same for someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

Under your sendMessage promise function, the resolve should be inside the callback of the sendMail function since it is asynchronous.

```js
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error,info){
       resolve();
    });
```

### UPDATE

Async stuff sometimes gets real tricky especially if you're used to synchronous processes. When I started on software this got me confused to.

You're promise functions are good. The problem there was that you were resolving the send function before it actually did it's job.

So below is a simpler version of your code. Doing the same thing you did

```js
// function that returns a message
// duration: 1s
function getMessage() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('important message'), 1000)
    });
}

// function that send a message using sendEmail function
// duration should be based on sendEmail
// notice that the resolve is called inside the callback
function sendMessage(message) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       sendEmail(message, (err, result) => {
           // do some stuff if email was sent
       })
       resolve();
    });
}

// function try to send an email asynchronously using a callback
// duration: 0.5s
function sendEmail(message, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('email sent!')
        callback(null, 'message sent');
    }, 500)
}

getMessage().then(result => {
    return sendMessage(result);
}).then(() => {
    console.log('should be done after email')
})
```

With the above code your terminal should show

```
should be done after email
email sent!
```

But with some modification on the sendMessage function

```js
function sendMessage(message) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       sendEmail(message, (err, result) => {
            resolve(result);
       })
    });
}
```

The terminal should now show

```
email sent!
should be done after email
```

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed info! Sorry for the delay. I understand that I need to move resolve within callbacks however I still get the mails being sent before the latest Drive sheet is retrieved. For now I am disregarding the messages until I understand the promise and resolve properly, thanks again!